In Ruby, how do you set the value for only one specific method argument, while just using the default values for other arguments?
Th parent_class instance variable for this class has a default value "String". I want to make an instance that has parent_class = "None". My super_string1 instance definition works correctly, but my super_string2 instance does not. What am I doing wrong for my super_string2 declaration?
class SuperString < String
  def initialize(str,id_num = 0,parent_class = "String")
    super(str)
    @id_num = id_num
    @str_length = str.length
    @creator = "Me"
    @parent_class = parent_class
  end
  
  attr_accessor :id_num, :str_length, :creator, :parent_class
end

super_string1 = SuperString.new("world", 0, "None")
puts super_string1.parent_class

super_string2 = SuperString.new("world", parent_class = "None") # This one doesn't work right
puts super_string2.parent_class

The output for this code is:
None
String


You want keyword arguments, i.e. parent_class: "None" (note the colon)

You're trying to write Python syntax in Ruby . Use keyword arguments, as other suggested.

Beware that subclassing String and any other class in the Ruby core is strongly recommended against. They are implemented in C and often do not behave as you would expect. The recommended solution is to instead use delegation so that your class encapsulates an instance of the core class.

You can use an optional keyword argument
 class SuperString < String
   def initialize(str, id_num: 0, parent_class: "String")
     super(str)
     @id_num = id_num
     @str_length = str.length
     @creator = "Me"
     @parent_class = parent_class
  end

  attr_accessor :id_num, :str_length, :creator, :parent_class
end

super_string1 = SuperString.new("world", id_num: 0, parent_class: "None")
super_string1.parent_class

super_string2 = SuperString.new("world", parent_class: "None")
super_string2.parent_class

super_string3 = SuperString.new("world")
super_string3.parent_class

"None"
"None"
"String"

https://www.ombulabs.com/blog/ruby/learning/methods-arguments-ruby-part2.html
